# Unable to test user authentication in symfony2

Tags: symfony, behat, fosuserbundle, mink

I'm using Symfony2 with Behat, Mink and the FosUser Bundle. The problem is that the login test always fails (the login works perfectly in development).

```
 Scenario: A user can login
    Given I am on "http://localhost:8888/myapp/web/login"
    And fill in "username" with "psitest@domain.pt"
    And fill in "password" with "pass"
    And press "login"
    Then I should see "Logout"
```

The test fails with The text "Logout" was not found anywhere in the text of the current page. 
Any idea on what's missing or how I could debug the problem?

I can test non-authenticated pages with Behat/Mink.

[Update]

The config_test is as follows (just the relevant bits):

```
## Security Configuration
security:
encoders:
    Symfony\Component\Security\Core\User\User: plaintext

providers:
    main:
        users:
            psitest@thisislove.pt: { password: senha, roles: ROLE_ADMIN }

firewalls:
    secured_area:
        pattern:    ^/
        http_basic: true
        logout:     true
        security: true
        anonymous: true
```

Comment: Also tried with other testing frameworks, standalone zombie.js and Story.php and they both fail so maybe it's something with the some cookie or token missing which causes the test to fail if not running in a browser?..

Comment: add mink config (from /app/config/config_test.yml) please

Answer (score 2):

"print last response" step should help you finding out what went wrong:

```
Scenario: A user can login
  Given I am on "http://localhost:8888/myapp/web/login"
    And fill in "username" with "psitest@domain.pt"
    And fill in "password" with "pass"
    And press "login"
    And print last response
   Then I should see "Logout"
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work probably because the user's password isn't **pass**, it's **senha**.

Comment: That's a typo, senha equals pass in portuguese. i simply changed it to english when i posted the first time and didn't change in the second time. In my test it's senha as it's supposed to be. Any idea what's wrong? Can you test authenticated pages using behat in symfony?

Comment: Which driver are you using with Mink?